# What does this exception class do?

Tags: java

I have created an Account Class that has within it a method for withdrawing money. If too much money is withdrawn, it throws an exception.

I need to make a JUnit test for an overdrawn account, but I think I'm having trouble creating it because I do not understand the example exception class I was provided with.

I was given this code. What does it do/return?

```
public class InsufficientFundsException extends Exception {

    private double amount;

    public InsufficientFundsException(double amount) 
        { 
           this.amount = amount; 
        }  
        public double getoverdrawn() 
        { 
           return amount; 
        } 
     }
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything.  It's just a class.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This class is of type Exception, and it is called InsufficientFundsException. This would probably be used in a case where the user is trying to make a purchase by calling a method that throws InsufficientFundsException. The method would then throw an InsufficientFundsException if the user does not have enough money. For example

```
public void purchase(Item i, double balance) throws InsufficientFunds Exception {
    //more codes here if we have enough money

    if (balance < i.getCost()) {
        throw new InsufficientFundsException(i.getCost() - balance); //throw an exception! we don't have enough money
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`InsufficientFundsException` is the exception that has to be thrown by `withdraw` method if the account doest not have sufficient funds.

```
public class Account {

    ...

    public void withdraw(double amount) throws InsufficientFundsException {
        if (amount > this.funds) {
            throw new InsufficientFundsException("put a cool message here", amount);
        }
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

You can test that exceptional case this way:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testWithdraw_InsufficientFunds() throws InsufficientFundsException {
    Account account = new Account(1500); // assuming that 1500 is current account fund
    thrown.expect(InsufficientFundsException.class);
    account.withdraw(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An exception is an event, which occurs during the execution of a program, that disrupts the normal flow of the program's instructions.

Here InsufficientFundsException  is special form of Exception.

for example, if we say we want user to limit withdrawal upto 100. We can use below code :

```
public int withdraw(double amount, int accountId , double balance) throws InsufficientFundsException  {

   if(amount>balance)
    throw new InsufficientFundsException (amount); 

    // withdrawl logic goes here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a class that can use to throw an exception. when initializing that class we can set the amount to that object. When  `throw new InsufficientFundsException(needs);`executed, exception trown and with InsufficientFundsException message.